# Efficiently find index of smallest number larger than some value in a large sorted list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, binary-search

If I have a long list of sorted numbers, and I want to find the index of the smallest element larger than some value, is there a way to implement it more efficiently than using binary search on the entire list?

For example:

```
import random
c = 0
x = [0 for x in range(50000)]

for n in range(50000):
    c += random.randint(1,100)
    x[n] = c
```

What would be the most efficient way of finding the location of the largest element in x smaller than some number, `z`

I know that you can already do:

```
import bisect
idx = bisect.bisect(x, z)
```

But assuming that this would be performed many times, would there be an even more efficient way than binary search? Since the range of the list is large, creating a dict of all possible integers uses too much memory. Would it be possible to create a smaller list of say every 5000 numbers and use that to speed up the lookup to a specific portion of the large list?

Comment: Without sacrificing memory or applying additional constraints, there probably isn't much you can do to improve the theoretical run-time function. What is the expected range of values that can appear in the list? What is its expected size? How many values are you going to search, and do you know all of them before the first search?

This paper details an approach to multiple-key binary search, you might want to take a look: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228409571_Multi-key_binary_search_and_the_related_performance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if this can be a solution?
It takes long to generate the list, but seems fast to report the result.

Given the list:

```
import random
limit = 50 # to set the number of elements
c = 0
x = [0 for x in range(limit)]

for n in range(limit):
    c += random.randint(1,100)
    x[n] = c
print(x)
```

Since it is a sorted list, you could retrieve the value using a for loop:

```
z = 1600 # reference for lookup

res = ()
for i, n in enumerate(x):
  if n > z:
    res = (i, n)
    break

print (res) # this is the index and value of the elements that match the condition to break
print(x[res[0]-1]) # this is the element just before
```

Comment: I don't see how this will be more efficient than just using `bisect`. Looping through the list is on average O(N/2) (Assuming equal probability), and bisect is on average O(lg N)

Comment: @C.J.Jackson, I run a benchmark using `timeit` 50 times on a list `limit = 500000` looking for an element at the end of the list (`z = x[-10]`). The `for` loop is slightly `faster` than `bisect` (1.8693751199999995 s Vs. 1.8854608779999997 s) on my machine.